# Set a ASP.NET webform to submit to a new window via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Is there a way in Javascript to set a ASP.NET webform to submit to a new window?  Simply put, when I click submit or press enter while in the form fields, I want the form to submit in a new window/tab.   I thought I could just do `jQuery('form').attr('target', '_blank');` but that is ignored, as if ASP.NET is taunting me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<button type="submit">one</button>
<button type="submit" class="popup">two</button>
</form>

$('.popup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('form').attr('target', '_blank').submit()
});
```

I found the answer in this link::

[setting target _blank for just one form submit action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484528/setting-target-blank-for-just-one-form-submit-action)

Comment: preventDefault() doesn't prevent the submission, as it seems ASP.NET webforms circumvents the standard form submission paradigm and disregards target='_blank'.